# finding element with dynamic attribute value

Tags: jquery

Trying to find the element value by

```
"QNTAnswer" : self.page.find("input[chkid='"+res[i]+"']").val(),
```

is not working , but if i hardcode the value like

```
"QNTQuestionComments" : self.page.find("textarea[chkid='1-IQL9LB']").val()
```

is working

Please help

Comment: have you check what is your res[i] value?

Comment: thanks all for help , somehow i messed up on the res[i] value , and was debugging for syntax issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With This

```
"QNTAnswer" : self.page.find("input[chkid=" + res[i] + "]").val()
```

If still not working then please try to find out the value of `input[chkid=" + res[i] + "]` using debugger.

Comment: @user3639535: Make sure your res[i] is not null or undefined. Also, you will not be able to find textarea as input.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your res[i] is not null or undefined. Also, you will not be able to find textarea as input.

Try as following:

```
"QNTAnswer" : res[i] != null ? self.page.find("textarea[chkid='"+res[i]+"']").val() : "your default value",
```